# Defining store dynamically on FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

I am trying dijit.form.FilteringSelect depending on the type defined in a response. While setting the store dynamically from the response I am getting an error :

SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

Below is the code :

```
var store=this.response.items[i].Name;
        var myTextBox = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
            title:this.response.items[i].DisplayName,
            name:this.response.items[i].Name,
            type:"picklist",
            value: "CA",
            store: this.response.items[i].Name,
            searchAttr: "name"  
    });

    debugger;
        dijit.byId("test").domNode.appendChild(myTextBox.domNode);

var Subsidiary = new dojo.store.Memory({

            data: [
                    {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
                    {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
                    {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
                    {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
                    {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
                    {name:"California", id:"CA"},
                    {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
                    {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
                    {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
                ]

        });
```

var MainClaimNumber = new dojo.store.Memory({

```
            data: [
                    {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
                    {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
                    {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
                    {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
                    {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
                    {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
                    {name:"California", id:"CA"},
                    {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
                    {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
                    {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
                ]

        });
```

As of now I know that there are 2 values with the type of FiltetringSelect so i am hardcoding the name of store.

Please guide how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the value of `this.response.items[i].Name`?  Somehow I doubt it's an entire store instance...

Comment: this.response.items[i].Name has value Subsidiary and MainClaimNumber for the first and second iteration and I have created the store name correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be expecting a string to magically interpolate to a variable.  This is not how JavaScript works.  You are defining variables within a function scope, and effectively setting `store: <some string>` and expecting `<some string>` to look up the variable of the same name...  but it's just going to be a string.  Moreover, it looks like you're not actually defining the variables in question until after you attempt to assign the store.

However, given what you want to do, you should be able to make some small adjustments to make it work, by creating your stores within an object hash instead, then use a string value to dynamically look up one of its keys:

```
var stores = {
    Subsidiary: new dojo.store.Memory(...),
    MainClaimNumber: new dojo.store.Memory(...)
};

var myTextBox = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    // ...
    store: stores[this.response.items[i].Name]
});
```